# What is Thomas Aquinas's "Dec. præc."?

Tags: reference-request, catholic-catechism, thomas-aquinas

The *Catechism of the Catholic Church* ([par. 1955](http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p3s1c3a1.htm)), cites "St. Thomas Aquinas, *Dec. præc.* I." What is the English (or even the Latin) name of this work "*Dec. præc.*"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Almost certainly this is a reference to his set of Sermons on the Ten Commandments known as ["Collationes in Decem Precepta"](https://aquinasinstitute.org/aquinas-opera-omnia/opuscula/) or ["de decem praeceptis"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_works_by_Thomas_Aquinas)